# Select by Location or Clip in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a polygon and also some point data 
I want to clip the point data so that I am to see all the points that aren't in  I want to see all points that aren't in the polygon boundary

Is there a simple way to do this in QGIS ?
I don't know whether I can invert the selection .
So my aim is to get a shapefile of all points that aren't contained in the polygon itself

Answer (score 1):

Use `Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Difference`, it's like the opposite of `Clip`.

Use the point layer as the `Input layer` and the polygon layer as the `Overlay layer`.